# How to Prevent Hotlinking by Using AWS WAF

Tags: amazon-waf

There is an AWS document that explains how to do it for oneself, i.e. how to allow only one's pages to hotlink and reject all others: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prevent-hotlinking-by-using-aws-waf-amazon-cloudfront-and-referer-checking/

I'd like to know if WAF is the right choice for my use case, which is a bit different from the one above.

- At the company I work for, we intend to sell data through a JS widget.
- We'd like to restrict access to those data so that only authorized REFERERs are able to show our data to their users, while rejecting all other REFERERs.
- The possibility of spoofing the REFERER is not an important threat for us.
- We expect to grow our customer base to some hundreds.

The reason I'm asking this question is due to noticing that there are some strict limits on WAF: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/limits.html, according to which I understand that for our use case, WAF wouldn't scale nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAF is not the right tool for that job.

First, even if there are max 10 rules, each with max 10 conditions, each with max 10 filters, there is a strong max of 100 string conditions per AWS account.

Second, conditions and filters do not compose nicely for our use case. Conditions of a rule get composed with an AND and filters of a condition get composed with an OR. For example, a rule like `r(x) := (x=a + x=b + x=c) * (x=d + x=e)` would give `r(d) = false` without ever getting to test `x=d`.